# React Native useEffect not run when app first opened

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I am trying to make an app where the `USER_ID` is loaded from the device's local storage if found, otherwise, a new id is generated and stored in the local storage. I am trying to make use of React `useContext()` to make the `USER_ID` visible to the whole app after it is first run.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';

export const UserIdContext = React.createContext('undef');

export const UserIdProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getOrInitUserId() {
      try {
        let temp = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID');
        if (temp == null) {
          temp = uuid.v4();
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_ID', uuid.v4());
          console.log('USER_ID Generated: ' + temp);
        } else {
          console.log('USER_ID Found: ' + temp);
        }
        setUserId(temp);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    if (!userId) {
      getOrInitUserId();
    }
  });

  return (
    <UserIdContext.Provider value={userId}>{children}</UserIdContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useUserId = () => React.useContext(UserIdContext);
```

The provider is used as below:

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ....
  });

  return (
    <UserIdProvider>
      ...contents of app...
    </UserIdProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

However, the `useEffect()` of `< UserIdProvider />` is not run as the app is launched for the first time after being installed on a device, as there is no log on the console. After the app is closed/quit and relaunched, the console log a `USER_ID` found, instead of `USER_ID` generated.

Comment: Try adding in the `[]` as your 2nd argument to your useEffect

Comment: Maybe the `AsyncStorage.getItem()` is only declared as async, but does not really run async under some conditions. How does the implementation of the function look like? If it returns a result right away, your console output will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add 2nd argument as [] so it will render only once. Otherwise, it will render every time when any state will be updated.

```
 const App = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        ....
      },[]);
    
      return (
        <UserIdProvider>
          ...contents of app...
        </UserIdProvider>
      );
    };

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger `useEffect` when first run you should enter `[]` as prop like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getOrInitUserId() {
      try {
        let temp = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID');
        if (temp == null) {
          temp = uuid.v4();
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_ID', uuid.v4());
          console.log('USER_ID Generated: ' + temp);
        } else {
          console.log('USER_ID Found: ' + temp);
        }
        setUserId(temp);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    if (!userId) {
      getOrInitUserId();
    }
  }, []);
```